# Get full results of query without install mongodb

Tags: windows, mongodb, robo3t

Im using a Windows computer that I dont have administrator access on (can't install programs).

I have a mongo query that will return >1 million results.

I would like to save all the results of this query to a file.

Since I can't install mongodb, I can't run this query using the mongo shell (at least the tutorial makes it seem that way). I have tried using robomongo, but I can't find a way to make robomongo spit out ALL the results of the query (without copy+pasting every set of 50). I'm able to use robomongo via a precompiled binary, which means it doesnt require installation.

This seems like an easy and common thing to do, what am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a way to download zipped mongo instalation from [main windows download page](https://www.mongodb.com/download-center?jmp=nav#community) search for [All Version Binaries](https://www.mongodb.org/dl/win32/x86_64-2008plus?_ga=1.20037948.526765052.1464620317) then download [win32/mongodb-win32-x86_64-2008plus-latest.zip](http://downloads.mongodb.org/win32/mongodb-win32-x86_64-2008plus-latest.zip?_ga=1.20032828.526765052.1464620317)

Then run mongoexport and enjoy!

```
mongoexport --db test --collection traffic --out c:\traffic.json
```

The other way is just to say robomongo that you want 1000000 documents :-)
please see below:

[image: roboMongo get more than 50 documents]

Enter the amount and hit enter.

Comment: Unfortunately, the robomongo "number of entries" only works when the query is a "find" while mine is an "aggregate" :(.

Ill try you're binary version tomorrow and mark as accepted if it works.